# how to display a arraylist in listview?

Tags: android

Can anybody help me to display the following arraylist in a listview.I am struck with this.
[E000199, E000100, ER008,EW999,EQ333,EQ111,E9089,E1001,E777,E999,E0123,E00054,E0032,E0016,E0016, E009, 
E008,E007,E005,E003,E001].

This is the response I get from a webservice.When I try to display it in a listview in another activity I am getting error as

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate().

pls help me.this is my code in second activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        }

    public void sendList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        this.emp_list=list;

        System.out.println("^^^^^^"+emp_list);

        adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list,R.id.title,emp_list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapt);

        setContentView(R.layout.viewlist);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem you must you custom adapter.

[LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183608/Android-Lists-ListActivity-and-ListView-II-Custom) for your reference

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewlist);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list,R.id.title,emp_list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapt);

    }

public void sendList(ArrayList<String> list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    this.emp_list.clear(); 
    this.emp_list.addAll( list ); 
    adapt.notifyDataChanged();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is...because you are trying to display ListView and setAdapter before setContentView() method.** Instead it should be as below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewlist);    // It should be here //1st solution

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        sendList(list);  // you forgot to call this method
     }

    public void sendList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        this.emp_list=list;

        System.out.println("^^^^^^"+emp_list);

        adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list,R.id.title,emp_list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapt);
    }
```

Comment: @user751828 make sure your list is not empty and viewlist is your xml layout contains listView1 as ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Just Keep `SetContentView(R.layout.viewlist);` after super Statement.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.viewlist);
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list,R.id.title,emp_list);
listview.setAdapter(adapt);

}
```

as `listview.setAdapter(adapt);` will directly Set the Value.

Answer (score 0):

before you'll get a view,you must call setContentView.so you can do like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewlist); //add this 
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        }

    public void sendList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        this.emp_list=list;

        System.out.println("^^^^^^"+emp_list);

        adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list,R.id.title,emp_list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapt);



    }
```